# iPhone - gcdasyncsocket delegate Didreceive does not work in other views

Tags: iphone, ios, c, udp

I am busy with an application to send and receive data through UDP.

When I start my application in view A, I initalize a new socket and setdelegate to self and bindtoport: 12345.

I am able to send and receive in this view.

Now when I go to the second view, I subclass view B to view A, I even tried to not subclass B to view A. And still I am not able to receive data in view B when I start initialization in the first view. So when I read this, Im thinking that the problem is that Im not closing the socket, and that there is something still going on and thats the reason why I cannot receive anything in my second view.

I tried to put [udpSocket close]; in viewDidUnload, but no succes.

Opinions plz...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in my viewDidLoad of the subclass I needed to add: [udpsocket beginreceiving];

I thought that by calling [super viewDidLoad];, this already happens because in my parent class I have stated that this method does get called.